# Chilkat Rest - How authorized with certificate

Tags: activex, visual-foxpro, chilkat

when I try to query a test, freely available, environment, the command below will return the required answer...

```
lnSuccess = loRest.Connect("https://api.test.....com", 443, 1, 1)
```

But how to ask the production environment where certificate verification is required?

Many thanks
J.B.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the Chilkat Socket object to connect, then use Rest.UseConnection.   See https://www.example-code.com/foxpro/rest_useSocketObject.asp

The reason Chilkat did it this way is to avoid needing to add all of the TLS connection related properties to Rest.  Instead, you can use the full flexibility of the Socket object to make the connection, then just tell Rest to use the already-established connection.

To make the TLS connection with certificate verification, call Socket.SetSslClientCert, SetSslClientCertPem, or SetSslClientCertPfx (see https://www.example-code.com/foxpro/socket_tlsClientCert.asp) prior to connecting.

Comment: Is it possible to use certificate from SmartCard ?